# How to return a re-tried response from axios interceptors

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, amadeus

I am an angular developer working on a react app and I am using axios for fetching some data from an API. I decided to use the interceptors provided by the library to make sure that for every request I check 401 authorization errors and if there are any to add the appropriate token and headers, if they exist and if not call the server request for them. The interceptors work as expected, meaning: when getting the authorization denied response it calls authorization endpoint sets the token and re-runs the request again.

Interceptors in index.js

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
  if(!request.url.includes('token')){
    request.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem('amadeus_token')
  }
  return request
})

axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
  return response
}, function(error){
  if(error.response.status === 401) {
     axios.post( `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token`, body)
    .then(result =>{
      localStorage.setItem('amadeus_token', `Bearer ${result.data.access_token}`)
      return axios.request(error.config);
    })
  }
}
)
```

Original calling function in my component App.js:

```
function getData() {
  axios.get('https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=MAD')
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data, 'data')
    if(!!data) {
      console.log(data, 'data from get')
      setState(data)
    } else {
    }
  }, function(error) {
    console.log(error.toJson())
  })
};
```

I am running into a weird race/timing issue where after I re-run the original request after getting the new token in the interceptor my original function is not listening for the response since the original response was returned.

What I Believe is happening is that when my function in APP.JS calls the get request, for the first call it is returning the Authorization Denied response, which resolves the Promise in the APP.js function, which means it is not waiting for the correct response to get back a few moments later from the interceptors.

A quick dirty way would be to call the get request again from App.JS but there has to be a better way since the interceptor is working as expected, and returning the correct response.

Update: Tried to call the same request from my component, that works but there has to be a way to stop the promise prematurely being fulfilled

Comment: Hi am new to React! Have you got solution for this issue, am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try let your interceptor like this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return response;
    },

  function(error){

  if(error.response.status === 401) {
     axios.post( `https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token`, body)
    .then(result =>{
      localStorage.setItem('amadeus_token', `Bearer ${result.data.access_token}`)
      return axios.request(error.config);
    })
  }
}
);
```